# Can't move content under nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to move links under my nav bar... I'm not sure what the issue is.. it's not budging. I'm trying to add margins to move the links over a bit. If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it! I also tried adding other content underneath such as a map, but it didn't appear on the page at all. Thanks in advance.

The CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: pink;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
    src: url('Fonts/ProximaNovaA-Regular.ttf');
}


/*---header/banner above the nav bar---*/
.blackbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}

#bag {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -42px; 
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#search {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-right: 110px;
    
}

#line {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -39px;
    margin-right: 92px;
}

#accent-shipping {
    background: #00A99D;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

/*---nav bar---*/
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 34px;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: ProximaNova
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a:hover, .menu:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

p {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
}

/*---links---*/
.links {
    margin-top: 50px;
}


and the HTML:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The Sock Factory</title>
    <link href="headerstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
</html>

<body>
<!--above nav bar-->
    <div class="blackbox"> </div>
    <img id="search" src="Contacts/search-01.png" width=auto height="30px">
    <img id="line" src="Contacts/line.png" width=auto height="30px">
    <img id="bag" src="Contacts/bag-01.png" width=auto height="35px">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="Contacts/logo.png" alt="home" width=auto height="110px"></a>
    <p id="accent-shipping">Free Shipping on all CAN orders</p>
    
<!--nav bar-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
            <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            <a href="shop.html">SHOP</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
<!--link-->
<div class="links">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> / <a href="contact.html"><span class="currentLink">Contact</span></a>
</div>

</body>
```

Please ignore the missing image:
[This is what i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wwO2.png)

Comment: why don't you use .links {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

Comment: that's what i'm trying to do, but it doesn't move at all when i add that into css.

Answer (score 0):

Following your image, I don't see where's the issue.

Using the following code

```
.links {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px
}
```

Makes the links appear the same place as in the image:

[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: pink;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
    src: url('Fonts/ProximaNovaA-Regular.ttf');
}


/*---header/banner above the nav bar---*/
.blackbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}

#bag {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -42px; 
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#search {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin-right: 110px;
    
}

#line {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -39px;
    margin-right: 92px;
}

#accent-shipping {
    background: #00A99D;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

/*---nav bar---*/
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 34px;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: ProximaNova
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a:hover, .menu:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

p {
    font-family: ProximaNova;
}

/*---links---*/
.links {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The Sock Factory</title>
    <link href="headerstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- add icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
</html>

<body>
    <!--above nav bar-->
    <div class="blackbox"></div>
    <img id="search" src="Contacts/search-01.png" width=auto height="30px">
    <img id="line" src="Contacts/line.png" width=auto height="30px">
    <img id="bag" src="Contacts/bag-01.png" width=auto height="35px">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="Contacts/logo.png" alt="home" width=auto height="110px"></a>
    <p id="accent-shipping">Free Shipping on all CAN orders</p>
    
    <!--nav bar-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a>
            <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            <a href="shop.html">SHOP</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--link-->
    <div class="links">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
        /
        <a href="contact.html"><span class="currentLink">Contact</span></a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I'm trying to move add margin-top and margin-left to slightly move it over... and it won't move when i put that

Comment: I'm not sure where should it be. Can you indicate it in a picture? I can modify margins and the elements move as expected.

Comment: Seems like the issue is different. Can you try with another browser? Maybe the page has other CSS that affects this rendering.

Comment: If you press `Run code snippet` do you see the links respecting the `margin-left` and `margin-top` properties?

Comment: It isn't appearing on mine like that, none of the CSS for the links are working at all for me.. it could be the program i'm using..

Comment: Yes, when I press run code snippet, it does appear.

Comment: I figured out the issue, it had to do with my stylesheet... sorry that was so dumb. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced but when I had a similar issue, using padding solved the problem. Try add some padding to the link as well. Eg.

```
.links {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Tried that too :( still doesn't move! Seems like my other css for the links aren't working either.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm still new here and figuring out how to post answers. It looks like your .navbar and .links need "display: block". If they are not block elements, then there is nothing for the margins to 'push against'